# Can I use multiple [element="..."] attribute selectors in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm using CSS to append an icon to on internal anchor tags. e.g.

```
<a href="#section2">Jump to section two</a>
```

But I don't want to append the icon to `href`s that are only `"#"` (JavaScript and top of page links). So a link like this wouldn't have an icon after it.

```
<a href="#">Back to top</a>
```

I'm trying to do it with CSS and not JavaScript.

Is this acceptable?

```css
a[href^="#"][href!="#"]:after {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Yes, multiple attribute selectors are allowed, and I don't think there's any specific requirement that they be different attributes.

Comment: Yes, it is acceptable

Comment: Yes, you can easily add even more conditions to the selector, but don't overdo it. I'd suggest trying to simplify the selectors as much as you can. This will enable you to more easily modify it later on. If `#section` is a standard prefix to you anchor tags you could just set the selector to `a[href^="#section"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) **are allowed** but there is no `[attr!=value]` attribute selector.

You could use [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot) pseudo-class to exclude `[href="#"]` from the selector:

```css
a[href^="#"]:not([href="#"]):after {
    content: ' \f14c';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

It's worth noting that `:not()` pseudo-class works on **[IE9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot#Browser_compatibility)**

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/daxun/1/edit)**.

Alternatively for IE8 *(while DOCTYPE is declared)*, you could also override the applied styles for the `[href="#"]` selector as follows:

```css
a[href^="#"]:after {
    content: ' \f14c';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

a[href="#"]:after {
    content: none;
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsbin.com/daxun/2/edit)**.